# Populate blank values in a Field with number from last populated value

Tags: sql, oracle9i

There is no specific number of blank values.  It can be none or many.  Here is the current result.

Blank Cells to be Populated:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions.  I think this will work:

```
select t.*, coalesce(coil, lag(coil ignore nulls) over (order by datetime))
from t;
```

I know Oracle has supported `ignore nulls` for a long, long time.  I don't quite remember off-hand if ancient versions supported it.

Comment: This has been a long time since I have responded.  I'm having trouble with "ignore nulls".  The error message tells me I'm missing a bracket.  Here is the code I'm using and the results.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @DavidHawkins . . . Oracle 11G definitely supports `IGNORE NULLS` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652).  Are you sure you are using that version?

Answer (score 0):

The below approach should work (or hopefully will give you enough to go on). The idea is that you update columns by joining a table on itself and joining on an earliest row which has been entered before the row you are wanting to update and also a row in which the column you are wanting to update is not NULL.

```
SELECT  YT1.ID, YT2.COIL
FROM Your_Table YT1
INNER JOIN Your_Table YT2 ON YT2.ID = 
(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Your_Table 
WHERE [start_date] < YT1.[start_date]
AND COIL IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [start_date] DESC)
WHERE YT1.COIL IS NULL OR LEN(YT1.COIL) = 0
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this concept.  Here is an example:  `Select
  ct.Start_Date
, ct.MTH  
, ct.DUR_MIN
, coalesce(ct.COIL, lag(ct.COIL ignore nulls) over (order by ct.Start_Date asc))
FROM
(
   select Start_Date, MTH, DUR_MIN, COIL COIL
      from  Table1 where 
   UNION ALL
   select Start_Date, MTH, DUR_MIN, NULL COIL
   from  Table2 where
   order by 1
  ) ct`

Comment: @DavidHawkins This concept doesn't look like the approach I suggested, you should maybe put this comment in the other answer if you prefer that approach

Comment: @ Vidmantas Blazevicius  Yes I agree.  I wanted you to see the 2 queries joined by the UNION ALL.  That was where I started. To use your example, I was struggling with the UPDATE and SET.  I assume the UPDATE could just be a SELECT.  The SET is used to do what exactly?

Comment: @DavidHawkins Oh ok, no problems, I updated my original answer with a SELECT instead of an update, only wrote UPDATE/SET because you wanted a script which populates blanks. So here the YT1.COIL will be your blank column and YT2.COIL will be the value that it should be, feel free to add extra columns.

Comment: @DavidHawkins Try now, I've also added your column names from the concept script in your first comment. You should only need to substitute `Your_Table` with your table name.